# How to export a completely transparent image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, transparency, png

For a game I’m making, I need a completely transparent image, i.e., every pixel shall have zero opacity.
I tried to make a completely transparent image in Photoshop, and try to save it as a PNG, but it doesn’t save.
I get no error message; the file just does not appear in the desired folder.
When I export a different file with opaque pixels, it works.

I managed to find a blank image online the right dimensions, but I would like to know why I can’t just do this in Photoshop or how I would be able to do it.

Comment: How are you saving/exporting the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you should be doing:

- Create a new document in Photoshop, give it any size you need and set the 'Background Contents' to 'Transparent'.
- Go to 'File → Save for Web', choose the PNG-24 format and tick the 'Transparency' box.
- Hit `Save`, give it a name and you're done.

Comment: No need to do anything to any background; just create the new file without one ... Do you happen to know what the OP did to make this not work? As for me, I'm unable to make it fail.